# call inline function of another header file from a header file c++

Tags: c++

I am having 2 header (.hh) files and there are some functions defined and implemented in both of these files:

What I want it so call a function of the other header file (let's call it B) from an implementation in header file A.

Here is what I have:

```
//headerA.hh
LSQUnit<Impl>::read(...args....)
   ...
callfunction(...args...);
}
```

where the implementation of call function is in the other header file like this:

```
// headerB.hh   
template<class Impl>
    inline void
    BaseDynInst<Impl>::callfunction (...args...){
       ....
    }
```

I have added in my headerA.hh these:

```
#include "headerB.hh"
....
void call function (...args...)
```

but I get undefined reference to callfunction in my headerA.hh

I have also tried these:

when I call it from headerA.hh

```
callfunction<BaseDynInst> callfunction (...args...)
```

or add this impleentation of this in my headerB.hh:

```
LSQUnit<Impl>::callfunction(...args...)
```

but they gave me more errors.

I know that putting implementations inside .hh may not be ideal but I am using a simulator which is not created by me, so I cannot change that because it will make things worse.

Is it possible what I want or the only solution is to implement the function inside headerA.hh ? I want to avoid that because it calls many others that all exist in headerB.hh?

Comment: If you're using templates, then putting implementations inside the header files is mandatory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems `callFunction` is a **non-static member function** of a template class. the corect way to call it is

```
LSQUnit<Impl> something;
something.callFunction(...);
```

That means you need an **object**  of the class type which owns `callFunction`. In this case `something`.

---

This syntax

```
LSQUnit<Impl>::callfunction(...args...)
```

is for calling [static](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/lnxpcomp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.xlcpp8l.doc/language/ref/cplr039.htm) member functions.